# How to remove white border in dialog?

Tags: android, dialog

I read many topics, but I didn't find answer of my problem. I'm trying to use `android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar` or xml styles with

```
<style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent_white</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

Even I have added

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.pixel);
```

where pixel is transparent drawable, but with no luck. I always have white border.

My code is below:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this,
android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.pixel);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
ListView modeList = new ListView(this);
String[] stringArray = new String[] { "aaa", "bbb" };
ArrayAdapter<String> modeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
stringArray);
modeList.setAdapter(modeAdapter);
builder.setView(modeList);
dialog = builder.create();
```

Regards,
Swierzy

Answer (score 2):

The white border of a dialog is a 9patch image
and your background picture has to be an 9patch picture. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

You can draw it yourself and make any border you like there.
you create your dialog like that

```
public AboutDialog(Context context) {
    super(context,R.style.Theme_Dialog);
   .......
```

and your style e.g.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="Theme" parent="android:Theme">
</style>
<style name="Theme.Dialog" parent="Theme">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>

    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>

    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg</item> <------- your 9patch background picture
</style>
```

---

hope this helps abit

Comment: thank You, i try this but there's still white border, im wondering is it problem of sense overlay

Comment: There will be no white border if you create style and image correctly and set the style for the dialog.

Comment: Set it as an answer then please if it did help you.